# Country to timezones in PHP/Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, timezone

Is there a way in Zend Framework or default PHP to map a country (using country code) to a list of timezones? As an example I'm trying to replicate the Google functionality when searching for "time in australia right now" which displays all of the timezones and cities for that country.

Comment: Could this be of help? http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.locale.date.datesandtimes.html#zend.locale.date.normalize

Answer (score 10):

Not sure about Zend_Date, but native PHP can do that as of PHP5.3 with

- [`DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)  — Returns numerically index array with all timezone identifiers

Example:

```
print_r( DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US') );
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => America/Adak
    [1] => America/Anchorage
    [2] => America/Boise
    [3] => America/Chicago
    [4] => America/Denver
    [5] => America/Detroit
    [6] => America/Indiana/Indianapolis
    [7] => America/Indiana/Knox
    [8] => America/Indiana/Marengo
    [9] => America/Indiana/Petersburg
    [10] => America/Indiana/Tell_City
    [11] => America/Indiana/Vevay
    [12] => America/Indiana/Vincennes
    [13] => America/Indiana/Winamac
    [14] => America/Juneau
    [15] => America/Kentucky/Louisville
    [16] => America/Kentucky/Monticello
    [17] => America/Los_Angeles
    [18] => America/Menominee
    [19] => America/New_York
    [20] => America/Nome
    [21] => America/North_Dakota/Center
    [22] => America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
    [23] => America/Phoenix
    [24] => America/Shiprock
    [25] => America/Yakutat
    [26] => Pacific/Honolulu
)
```

Note that the country must be supplied as a two-letter ISO 3166-1 compatible country code. Apparently, this means 'us' is not the same as 'US' (at least I don't get a result then).

Comment: Any idea how to do on php 5.2

Comment: @Flakerim nope sorry. But why are you still on 5.2 anyway? It has reached end of life support. Update :)

Comment: Yeah, you right, but we need to upgrade our IT first :). Thanks for answer.